# Android: myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix Too Slow

Tags: android, google-maps

Does anybody have any ideas in speeding up the process for setting the initial point for Google Maps, centering on your current location. This must be possible as it works fine in the native Google Maps app but has a noticeable delay in my custom application where I am using:

```
myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {             
            findMe();
        }           
    });
```

where find me includes:

```
if(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation() != null){
    mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the native Maps service and application is loading on system startup and prepares itself in the background wchich makes it load maps faster. You could check it in running processes in the settings. You cloud do the same or make dirty workaround wchich I did once: display progress dialog before everything load (after setContentView in onLoad) and close it after you done everything on the map you need ;)

Comment: That sounds great however is there a way to get the location from that background service?

Comment: Of course. You need to launch service in background from first activity or on [startup](http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/starting-android-service-at-boot-time.html) (define in manifest, create service connection and AIDL interface). The service will provide methods like getLatitude() getLongitude() as primitives like Double. The service will have to register LocationListener. For further reading: [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html), [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using only GPS location? If you request the current location based on the network location and accept a little stale values (up to an hour maybe?), you should get the user's location practically immediately.

Comment: How would you set network service only for 'myLocationOverlay'? As I imagine the time issue is due to waiting on all services to become available?

Comment: You can still listen to GPS location events as before. But instead of waiting for first GPS fix, you can run findMe() immediately when your activity starts using Location value provided by LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); You can of course also try to check if a last known GPS_PROVIDER location is available and is not too old for you.
If you don't care about accurate location, but network location is good enough for you, you can register your LocationListener for NETWORK_PROVIDER updates.